# Android, Google Maps won't show

Tags: android, maps

I'm making an app that needs to show a location that I define with latitude and longitude. Everything goes fine, it opens Google maps in my app screen but the maps won't show up!
This is the code I use...

```
public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity {

MapView mapView;
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //vraag custom title bar
    requestCustomTitle();
    setContentView(R.layout.mapsactivity);
    //Titel dynamisch invullen volgens taalvoorkeuren, roept methode setCustomTitle op
    setCustomTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.MapsTitel));


    showZoom();
    locate(getIntent().getStringExtra("kantoorLat"), getIntent().getStringExtra("kantoorLng"));
    addMarker();

}
/*
 * De methode showZoom zorgt ervoor dat de zoombuttons worden getoond
 */

private void showZoom(){
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls();

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);
}

/*
 * De methode locate zorgt ervoor dat de juiste locatie wordt getoond
 */
private void locate(String strlat, String strlng){
    mc = mapView.getController();
    String coordinates[] = {strlat,strlng};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));
    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17);
    mapView.invalidate();
}

/*
 * De methode addMarker zorgt ervoor dat er een indicator staat op de locatie
 */
private void addMarker(){
    MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
    List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    listOfOverlays.clear();
    listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
}

protected boolean isRouteDisplayed(){
    return false;
}

class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay{
    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when){
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        Point screenPts = new Point();
        mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p,screenPts);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.accentindicator);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x+7, screenPts.y-19, null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: so you see just the grid right? Have you specified the maps api key?

Comment: Have you given the correct API key? and `InternetPermissions` to your application?

Comment: I have specified my API key in my layout XML file. I'm seeing the grid, Google's logo and my marker.

Comment: hope you have specified the Map API key

Comment: have you specified uses-library com.google.android.maps in XML??

Comment: I have a correct api key (the map worked just fine several days ago), I see Google's logo, my marker and have specified these permissions
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
              <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />`

Comment: @Hannelore i hope you have not changed your pc.if you have changed your pc then regenerate the MD5 key.

Comment: @Harshad I think that's the problem. We're working with SVN client...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MD5 key will not work on different machines.

You need to generate MD5 debug key for the current SDK that you are using.

Generate the debug key for your current machine and try again.

Comment: I had to replace the debug.keystore again, I'm fine now, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Get a **API key** here

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

Put the **following rule** in your AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following blog entry that lists down the reasons that might cause this issue.
http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/01/18/using-google-maps-in-your-android-app/

Besides the activity, its also the manifest, the layout or the API key that can be invalid.

In short

- The Android SDK needs to be setup to
  support Google Maps.
- A MapView
  component needs to be added to your
  layout, containing a valid Google
  Maps API key
- The Activity that will
  be responsible for showing the map
  needs to extend from MapActivity
- The
  application manifest needs to be
  setup with the
  android.permission.INTERNET
  permission
- The application manifest
  needs to be setup with the
  com.google.android.maps library

In your case, it's most likely internet connectivity (permisson in manifest and/or emulator internet access) or an invalid API key. Keep in mind that the API key is linked to the certificate used to sign your APK.

Comment: I generated my API key following this tutorial: [link]http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android
It has worked before, but now it doesn't. I work with my partner, using SVN client. I've requested a new key, but it still doesn't work. It shows only a grid, the Google logo, zoombars and my marker.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the key to access Google map in your application and after getting key you have to add library in ue manifest file which will be installed automatic when u got the key.

Answer (score 0):

I think its your emulator version problem.Android sdk 2.2 emulators some times doesnot show the exact location.Try to run  emulator 2.1 .

Comment: My emulator is Google API level 4

Answer (score 0):

Even using the **Google API Introduction** I have had problems like this.

I **followed** this tutorial and it worked for me:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Good luck,